# CF7 Submit Popup

Tags: plugins

I have six  CF7 forms and I would like to make a popup on particular form after submitting it. **Contact Form 7 Response Colorbox Popup** won't do since it affects all forms. Can anyone help me, I'm not that familiar with jquery but if someone can guide me it will be a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try contact form [DOM Events](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/)

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
        switch(event.detail.contactFormId){
            case "220": case "222": 
                //show popup
            break;

            default : console.log("Error");break;
        }
```

Find your id from shortcode :

```
[contact-form-7 id="223" title="Careers Entry Form"]
```